# What value the rear and front counter of an Array implementation of Queue start with? -1 or 0 or 1?

Tags: c, array, queue

Is there anything wrong with this implementation of Queue with array?

I have started front = rear = -1.

Some references tend to start front = 0 like this:[enter link description here](http://hamilton.bell.ac.uk/swdev2/notes/notes_13.pdf)

I think if front starts with 0, the source code becomes cumbersome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define SIZE 5

int queue[SIZE] = {0};
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;

void PrintQueue()
{
    int i=0;

    if(!IsEmpty())
    {
        for(i=front+1 ; i<=rear ; i++)
        {
            printf("%d, ", queue[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n");
    }
}

int IsEmpty()
{
    if(front==rear)
    {
        front = rear = -1;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void Enque(int value)
{
    if(rear<SIZE-1)
    {
        ++rear;
        queue[rear] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue overflow!\n");
    }
}

int Dequeue()
{
    int ret = 0;
    if(!IsEmpty())
    {
        ++front;
        ret = queue[front];
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue underflow!\n");
        ret = -99;
    }

    return ret;
}

main()
{
    int value = 0;
    int menu = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("--------\n");
        printf("1. Enque\n");
        printf("2. Deque\n");
        printf("3. IsEmpty\n");
        printf("4. Print\n");
        printf("5. Clrscr\n");
        printf("6. Exit\n");
        scanf(" %d", &menu);

        switch(menu)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter an element : ");
            scanf(" %d", &value);
            Enque(value);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Dequed, %d.\n", Dequeue());
            break;

        case 3:
            if(IsEmpty())printf("Queue is empty.\n");
            else printf("Que has some values.\n");
            break;

        case 4:
            PrintQueue();
            break;

        case 5:
            system("cls");
            break;

        case 6:
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Enqueue** and **Dequeue**

Comment: COULD NOT UNDERSTAND!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most implementations of a Queue use `front` to point to the head element of the queue and `rear` to point to the first empty element at the rear of the queue:

```
front       rear
v            v
[1][2][3][4][ ][ ]
```

Your implementation has them pointing one element previous.

To change your code to work like this would be a matter of change front/rear to start at 0 and then reversing your increment/read:

```
void Enqueue(int value)
{
    if(rear<SIZE-1)
    {
        queue[rear] = value;
        ++rear;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue overflow!\n");
    }
}
```

Review:

Your `IsEmpty` function has the side effect of resetting the queue. The name does not reflect this; it sounds like it should be merely checking whether the queue is empty. There's not really anything wrong with that. Pragmatically, such an operation should be transparent. However, I'd put a comment in there describing the side effect.

You could also implement a [circularly linked queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_queue) in which you insert elements in a (conceptual) ring. Basically, when you get to the end of the array, you start inserting at the begining again. However, this means that when `front = back` the buffer could be full *or* empty. Just check `rear + 1` to see if it's empty.

Oh, and *please* spell "queue" and its varients correctly...it's really bugging me :)